# Putting custom values into application.properties

Tags: grails, bamboo

When I build my grails war I would like to put custom properties into my application.properties file?

For example, suppose I have a custom property `build.by=tony magoo` and I want to add this to my application.properties.

Now this isn't just editing a text file. I am using bamboo to build the wars.
I build several versions of the war and I want to specify particular properites in the grails war command so that get this information  from war after it is built.

Comment: Could you clarify the question? I believe you know how to edit text file. And as I see from your previous question you know how to read from this file. So, what's the question?

Comment: Ok, I see. It's unrelated to Grails, it's about Bamboo. I'm going to set correct tags for the question

Comment: @IgorArtamonov but in bamboo all I do it run a grails war command. I run a slightly different grails war command for each plan.  I just need to pass in different values to each application.properties file for each bamboo plan, which shouldn't change.  So I see it more as a grails question.

Comment: But why Grails? just run another command, that will generate your files, before running `grails war`

Comment: btw, I've returned #grails tag back

Answer (score 0):

You can change you file using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed&ei=4s1SUrLYD8jV4gTL0YCwBw&usg=AFQjCNGCbrHLLTC-BFFAgDRgctXak5hnDg&sig2=_Y5w_Lk5qzVIIc44PilXug&bvm=bv.53537100,d.bGE) in script task.
Just create new script task and write into inline editor

```
sed '$ a\ build.by=tony magoo' <path/to/your/apllicaton.properties>
```

It will add this string to the end of file.

You should execute script task before create war